# Finding Integers to Sum to 1200

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> $125x_1+25x_2+5x_3+x_4=1200$
>
> Find all ordered pairs of integers such that $0 \leq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4
>  \leq 25$.

Is there any systematic way of approaching this? Or do you need to solve by cases?

Comment: A drop in the ocean: $x_4$ is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: @DanielR But $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ can't all be zero  due to the constraint $0\leq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \leq 25$; otherwise, you'd then have $x_4=1200\notin [0,25]$.

Comment: @DanielR: but then $x_4$=1200, which is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Wow, forgot to think. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need to split into cases, but splitting is not that bad. Here's my "kind of systematic" case splitting method. First start by expressing $1200$ in base $5$:
$$
1200_{10} = 14300_5.
$$
This problem can be seen as generalizing the base-5 representation so that each digit can  be as large as $25$. This makes it possible to write $1200$ with only four digits:
$$
1200 = [1][4][3][0][0] = [0][9][3][0][0]
$$
where the brackets represent digits in base 5. $[9][3][0][0]$ is the *minimal* choice. (The sum of digits is minimal.) Other choices can be obtained by *pushing digits to the right*. That means any digit greater than $0$ can be pushed to the right, decreasing it by $1$, and increasing the digit to the right by $5$.

The following are minimal choices with fixed leftmost digit:
\begin{gather}
[9][3][0][0] \\
[8][8][0][0] \\
[7][13][0][0] \\
[6][18][0][0] \\
[5][23][0][0] \\
[4][25][15][0]
\end{gather}
Because of the upper bound constraint, we can push a certain digit at most $6$ times. (Why?) That means except the first and the last cases, all the remaining four cases give the same number of choices, which is equal to the number of representations of
$$
[6][0][0].
$$
Let us count this first. Split into cases of pushing the middle digit after pushing the first digit:
\begin{align}
[6][0][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ cannot push anymore } \Rightarrow 1 \text{ choice}\\
[5][5][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[4][10][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[3][15][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[2][20][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[1][25][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[0][25][25] & \Rightarrow \text{ cannot push anymore } \Rightarrow 1 \text{ choice}
\end{align}
This means $[6][0][0]$ has $32$ different representations. The same holds for $[n][0][0]$ for any $n \ge 6$.

We are left with two cases: $[3][0][0]$ and $[25][15][0]$. The case of $[3][0][0]$ is similar to $[6][0][0]$ with the last three subcases removed:
\begin{align}
[3][0][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ cannot push anymore } \Rightarrow 1 \text{ choice}\\
[2][5][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[1][10][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[0][15][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}
\end{align}
The total number of choices is $19$.

The case of $[25][15][0]$ is similar to $[6][0][0]$ with the first three subcases removed:
\begin{align}
[25][15][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[24][20][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[23][25][0] & \Rightarrow \text{ can push up to $5$ times } \Rightarrow 6 \text{ choices}\\
[22][25][25] & \Rightarrow \text{ cannot push anymore } \Rightarrow 1 \text{ choice}
\end{align}
The total number of choices is $19$.

Therefore, there are $19 + 4 \times 32 + 19 = 166$ quadruples.

Answer (score 0):

1200 and $125x_1+25x_2$ are multiples of 25, so $5x_3+x_4$ must be too.
How many ways can $5x_3+x_4$ equal 0? 25? 50? 75? 100? 125? 150?
How many ways can $125x_1+25x_2$ equal 1200? 1175? 1150? 1125? 1100? 1075? 1050?